# bundling failed Unexpected token react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm new at react native :D so..
I'm trying to build a simple page with inline style and when I use {{ like `style={{}}` return for me this `error: Unexpected token` and when I write like this `style={}` app run successfully but style not working
it's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';



import styles from "./outStyles";

class App extends Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <View style={{flex=1}}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor='#f00',flex=1}} ></View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor='#00f',flex=9}} > 
        <Text>Usee First Project anbari</Text>
         </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor='#00',flex=1}} ></View>
      </View>
    );
  };

}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first set of curly braces in JSX indicates you are passing it a parameter. The second set in your example indicates that parameter is an object. But, your are not using valid JS object syntax. So instead of:

```
<View style={{backgroundColor='#f00',flex=1}} ></View>
```

Do this:

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#f00', flex: 1 }} ></View>
```

It might be clearer for you if you separate your style object, like setting it up in your constructor:

```
this.styles = {
    backgroundColor: '#f00', 
    flex: 1
};
```

Then in your render you could do:

```
<View style={this.styles} ></View>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the style to the `<View>`, tags are expecting style objects. So this is not going to work...

```
style={{ backgroundColor='#f00', flex=1 }}
```

It should be `:` not `=`, So this is how you should apply it...

```
style={{ backgroundColor:'#f00', flex:1 }}
```